# Implement adapter design pattern in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-5.6

I tried to implement adapter design pattern in my laravel application.
I had to use more than cloud to upload images ex.(google cloud storage, amazon s3).

1- I created an interface called ImageUploderInterface.

2- I created to classes AmazonCloudFrontService class and GoogleCloudStorageService each one of them implement ImageUploderInterface.

3- I created service provider to register my interface and return specific object from one class (AmazonCloudFrontService  OR GoogleCloudStorageService) depend on env varaible.

4- I registered my service provider in config/app.php.

5- then I try to inject the ImageUploderInterface in my controller But I had an error that the interface doesn't exit.

**image upload interface**

```
<?php

namespace App\Interfaces;

interface ImageUploderInterface
{   
   public function uploadImage($file, $uploadFolder);

   public function retrieveImage($fileName, $uploadFolder);
}
```

**service provider**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Providers;

 use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
 use App\Interfaces\ImageUploderInterface;
 use App\Services\AmazonCloudFrontService;
 use App\Services\GoogleCloudStorageService;

class ImageUploadServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(ImageUploderInterface::class, function ($app)         {
        switch ($app->make('config')->get('services.image-uploader')) {
            case 'amazon':
                return new AmazonCloudFrontService;
            case 'gcs':
                return new GoogleCloudStorageService;
            default:
                throw new \RuntimeException("Unknown upload image Service");
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Error**

> message: "Class App\Interfaces\ImageUploadInterface does not exist", exception: "ReflectionException",…}
>   exception: "ReflectionException"
>   file: "/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
>   line: 826
>   message: "Class App\Interfaces\ImageUploadInterface does not exist"

Comment: please paste the code instead of an image with specific details

Comment: @PatelRomil I added the code